# Write Unicode (UTF-8) text file

Tags: delphi, unicode, character-encoding, text-files, delphi-10.3-rio

How can I write a Unicode text file in Delphi?

Currently I simply use `AssignFile`, `RewriteFile`, and `Writeln`, but this does not write Unicode characters.

Comment: Why are you using 1980 file I/O in modern versions of Delphi? Use `TFileStream` instead. It's existed for more than 2 decades now. You're using file I/O that is from Turbo Pascal 1. Even using a `TStringList.SaveToFile` would be better when dealing with text files.

Comment: Or even better, use [`TStreamWriter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter) instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You shouldn't be using old Pascal I/O at all. That did its job back in the 80s but is very obsolete today.

---

This century, you can use the [`TStringList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStringList). This is very commonly used in Delphi. For instance, VCL controls use `TStrings` to access a memo's lines of text and a combo box's or list box's items.

```pascal
var SL := TStringList.Create;
try
  SL.Add('∫cos(x)dx = sin(x) + C');
  SL.Add('¬(a ∧ b) ⇔ ¬a ∨ ¬b');
  SL.SaveToFile(FileName, TEncoding.UTF8);
finally
  SL.Free;
end;
```

Fore more advanced needs, you can use a [`TStreamWriter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter):

```pascal
var SW := TStreamWriter.Create(FileName, False, TEncoding.UTF8);
try
  SW.WriteLine('αβγδε');
  SW.WriteLine('ωφψξη');
finally
  SW.Free;
end;
```

And for very simple needs, there are the new [`TFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile) methods in `IOUtils.pas`:

```pascal
var S := '⌬ is aromatic.';
TFile.WriteAllText(FileName, S, TEncoding.UTF8);         // string (possibly with linebreaks)

var Lines: TArray<string>;
Lines := ['☃ is cold.', '☼ is hot.'];
TFile.WriteAllLines(FileName, Lines, TEncoding.UTF8);    // string array
```

As you can see, all these modern options allow you to specify UTF8 as encoding. If you prefer to use some other encoding, like UTF16, that's fine too.

---

Just forget about `AssignFile`, `Reset`, `Rewrite`, `Append`, `CloseFile` etc.

Answer (score 5):

Other users have given you options but nobody has answered (I guess). You can´t write UTF8 using `Writeln` because at runtime, any string is switched back to Ansi. All the proposal seems very good ones however.

Try this short program

```
program utf8;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var s : string; u : AnsiString;   some : Text;

begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    Assign(some,'data.txt');
    rewrite(some);
    s := 'física';
    u := UTF8Encode (s);
    writeln(some,s);
    writeln(some,u);
    Close(some);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Enable "use debug dcu" and carefully follow the `Writeln` execution. You will learn that despite the fact of being UTF8 encoded, `u` is switched back to Ansi at some point.

Edition:
I was wrong. You can indeed with:

```
Assign(FileName,CP_UTF8);
```

Check help for `System.Assign`